# How preact does smart diff-render natively?

Tags: reactjs, preact

It says that it uses **native DOM for smart diff-render** instead of custom implementation like in React.

But how is that possible? Does browsers support smart diff-render now?

Answer (score 3):

Preact implements a custom diff algorithm like React, it just compares virtual DOM elements to existing DOM elements.

Here's a visual representation of how that differs between the two libraries:

[image: preact vs react diff internals]